# Fetching posts from wordpress function in ajax

Tags: loop, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to fetch posts in ajax. Everything is working but It is showing only one post. Please check my code and tell me if something is wrong

```
function ag_get_posts() {
    global $post;
    $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'post',
      'posts_per_page' => 12,
      'post_status' => 'publish',
    );

query_posts( $args );


while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
locate_template( 'post.php', TRUE, TRUE );
 endwhile;

wp_reset_query();
    exit;
}

add_action('wp_ajax_ag_get_posts', 'ag_get_posts');
```

**jQuery:**

```
var data = {
    action: 'ag_get_posts',
};

jQuery.post(AjaxPath.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
var result = $(response)
    Content.html(result);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the documentation for [`locate_template`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/locate_template) you'll see the problem.

```
locate_template( $template_names, $load, $require_once );
```

> $require_once
>   (boolean) (optional) If true, the template file will be loaded with the php require_once function. If false, the template file will be loaded with the php require function. This parameter has no effect if $load is false.
>   Default: true

PHP won't load your template more than once because you've set `$require_once` to true.

A simpler API function for this purpose is [`get_template_part`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part):

```
get_template_part( 'post' );
```

Comment: But get_template_part doesn't work in functions.php. This function is made for template files only. I just set `$require_once` to FALSE, now its working. :)

Comment: Just checked, `get_template_part();` also worked. Thanks for the tip.